# Checking if no elements in IEnumerable(Of T) - Linq element and quantifier operators

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, element

For my function

```
IEnumerable<CallbackListRecord> LoadOpenListToProcess(CallbackSearchParams usp);
```

This line errors when the sequence contains no elements (as it should)

```
CallbackListRecord nextRecord = CallbackSearch.LoadOpenListToProcess(p).First();
```

I have changed it to the following

```
CallbackListRecord nextRecord = null;
IEnumerable<CallbackListRecord> nextRecords = CallbackSearch.LoadOpenListToProcess(p);
if (nextRecords.Any())
{
    nextRecord = nextRecords.First();
}
```

Are there better, easier or more elegant ways to determine if the IEnumerable sequence has no elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try to avoid enumerating it more times than necessary (even if short-circuited, like `First` and `Any`) - how about:

```
var nextRecord = CallbackSearch.LoadOpenListToProcess(p).FirstOrDefault();
if(nextRecord != null) {
    // process it...
}
```

This works well with classes (since you can just compare the reference to null).

Comment: Any specific reason to use the var keyword in this case?

Comment: @boon - well, it's shorter...  No, using var is always equivalent to the type the compiler resolves var to be (CallbackListRecord in this case).

Comment: @boon - one very simple reason; without it the text scrolled off the page ;-p

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten the code to the following

```
var nextrecord = CallbackSearch.LoadOpenListToProcess(p).FirstOrDefault();
```

nextrecord will either contain the First element if there was one or null if the collection was empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you are anticipating that there could be null values in the sequence, you could handle the enumerator yourself.

```
var enumerator = CallbackSearch.LoadOpenListToProcess(p).GetEnumerator();
if (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
  var item = enumerator.Current;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an extension method like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool HasElements<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        foreach (T t in collection)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault is better because you at least get an instance of the first record then

Comment: FirstOrDefault will give problems if you are enumerating structs rather than classes if you check for null to see if there are any elements. But yes, if you hold that in account it would be faster.

Comment: But you wouldn't check for null. In the case of IEnumerable<int> you would say "if (nextRecord == default(int))", although this could be ambiguous when there are potentially zeros in the collection.  Maybe better to call ToArray() or ToList() and check its length in that case, and get the first item by index.